# Finding the 'type' of an input element

Tags: javascript

I'd like to be able to find the type of something on the page using JavaScript.
The problem is as follows:
I need to check whether a specific area is a checkbox/radio button/ or text field.

If it's a checkbox or radio button it doesn't have a length (no strings in it), otherwise if it's a textfield I need to check whether or not it contains characters. The page is created dynamically so sometimes a checkbox may be displayed, other times a text field.

So my thinking is to find the type of the input, then determine what to do.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a big deal, but a more careful distinction would have been in order here: "Type of an input element" differs massively from "Type of a variable" or "type of some other element on the page".

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Check the `type` property. Would that suffice?

Comment: use it like element.type, it would return textarea it the element is a textarea and so on.

Comment: And if an element is an input, then `.type` will return `text`, `checkbox`, `radio`, etc.

Comment: `HTMLInput​Element.type`, more precisely.

Answer (score 47):

If you want to check the type of input within form, use the following code:

```
<script>
    function getFind(obj) {
    for (i = 0; i < obj.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (obj.childNodes[i].tagName == "INPUT") {
            if (obj.childNodes[i].type == "text") {
                alert("this is Text Box.")
            }
            else if (obj.childNodes[i].type == "checkbox") {
                alert("this is CheckBox.")
            }
            else if (obj.childNodes[i].type == "radio") {
                alert("this is Radio.")
            }
        }
        if (obj.childNodes[i].tagName == "SELECT") {
            alert("this is Select")
        }
    }
}
</script>     

<script>    
    getFind(document.myform);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using jQuery you can easily check the type of any element.

```
    function(elementID){    
    var type = $(elementId).attr('type');
    if(type == "text") //inputBox
     console.log("input text" + $(elementId).val().size());
   }
```

similarly you can check the other types and take appropriate action.

Comment: Or, if you use Javascript, you could write `document.getElementById(elementId).type`. I fail to see the benefit that jQuery gives in this case.

Comment: This is a function (means overhead), in a non-jQuery style ( eg not `.getType()`, doesn't have a functionname and does nothing more than `$(element)[0].type` (assuming you allready had the jQuery object)

Answer (score 1):

**To check input type**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <input type=number id="txtinp">
    <button onclick=checktype()>Try it</button>

    <script>
        function checktype() 
        {
            alert(document.getElementById("txtinp").type);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```